# How to get a control's GUID

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Checkbox` array. I placed it in a `Listview`. I set the `CheckedChanged` event handler for them. The `CheckedChanged` event fires successfully and I want to get the GUID of the control from the sender object. How can I get the GUID?

```
_ckeckBox[i].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(frmMain_CheckedChanged);

void frmMain_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by GUID? If you want a reference to your CheckBox you can simply do: `var checkBox = sender as CheckBox`.

Comment: i have many checkbox and have to determine which ckeckbox is checked.

Comment: I always thought Winforms controls didn't have Guids? There's not COM. Look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/53188d51-6252-464a-b931-5665dbad16f4)

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you would normally get the GUID? This isn't a default property, so I'm thinking it's something you've added or are inferring. As Eve said, then `sender` property tells you which checkbox the event is for, and can be easily cast to a `CheckBox`.

Comment: if they don't have GUID. then how can i determine which Checkbox is checked? thanks in advance

Comment: in the function "CheckedChanged" one of the parameter is the checkbox checked ("sender")

Comment: @Rezoan: eve, in the very first comment give you the anwser. Maybe eve can post it as an answer, where you can comment if you don't understand something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commentators have mentioned, the sender parameter tells you which control is calling the event:

```
void frmMain_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
  if (cb != null) {
    MessageBox.Show("Checked " + cb.Name);
  }
}
```

Comment: i do it using tag. thanks  void frmMain_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
            if (chk != null && chk.Tag != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(chk.Tag.ToString()))
            {
                NodeManager.UpdateNodeActive(chk.Tag.ToString(), chk.Checked);

                _isCheckUncheckQueued = true;
                ProcessQueuedNodeList();
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

```
 void frmMain_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
            if (chk != null && chk.Tag != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(chk.Tag.ToString()))
            {
                NodeManager.UpdateNodeActive(chk.Tag.ToString(), chk.Checked);

                _isCheckUncheckQueued = true;
                ProcessQueuedNodeList();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not such a "control guid"..

You can determine wich one was invoked using hes unique ID.

Comment: is there any sample or link form where i can understand it. thanks Oscar

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Name` property in Win forms to determine which checkbox gets checked.